# ethereum blockchain implement proof of identity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

IS it possible somehow with ethereum smart contract implement proof of identity and email check?

IS there a need to do external call or everything can be implemented in blockchain. How to add then new identity to blockchain to check it later?

I am searching this topic for a while without any success.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to manage the identities of your users via Ethereum. So, when they acces to your app, they will be signed up via Ethereum. Then, they will verify their account via an email that your app will send. After that, their Ethereum states would be changed. Am I right? I think that if I'm right, you have here the solution.

For that you have many choices:

- You can develop a Smart Contract for that.
- You can use [uport](https://www.uport.me/)